# Best approach to process batch API Request Lavel 5

Tags: php, api, laravel, batch-processing, laravel-5.1

**EDIT** : Already fixed the error `Creating default object from empty value` . My question now is just suggestions how to make this process better.

I am making a tool that sends batch API request to a certain URL. I am using https://github.com/stil/curl-easy for batch API request That API will validate the phone numbers I am sending and return a result. That API can support maximum 20 request per second, supposed I have 50,000 API request, what is the best and fastest way to process things?

The current process is, I query to my database for the number of records I have which is the number of phone numbers. Then I make a loop with the number of phone numbers. Inside a single iteration, I will query 13 records from the database then pass it to the queue and process it, when the processing is finished I will query again to the database and update the fields for the the phone number based on the API response. My problem is that I think I have a logic error on my loop when I run this the processing will stop for sometime and gives me:

```
Creating default object from empty value
```

I guess that is because of my loop here's my code.

```
public function getParallelApi()
{

    $numItems = DB::connection('mysql')->select("SELECT COUNT(ID) AS cnt FROM phones WHERE status IS NULL");

    for($y = 0; $y < $numItems[0]->cnt; $y++)
    {
        $queue = new \cURL\RequestsQueue;
        // Set default options for all requests in queue
        $queue->getDefaultOptions()
        ->set(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5)
        ->set(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)
        ->set(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


        // This is the function that is called for every completed request
        $queue->addListener('complete', function (\cURL\Event $event) {
            $response = $event->response;
            $json = $response->getContent(); // Returns content of response
            $feed = json_decode($json, true);

            $phone_number = $feed['msisdn'];
            if(isset($phone_number))
            {
                $status = "";$remarks = "";$network = ""; $country = "";$country_prefix = "";

                if(isset($feed['status']))
                {
                    $status = $feed['status'];
                }

                if(isset($feed['network']))
                {
                    $network = $feed['network'];
                }

                if(isset($feed['country']))
                {
                    $country = $feed['country'];
                }

                if(isset($feed['country_prefix']))
                {
                    $country_prefix = $feed['country_prefix'];
                }

                if(isset($feed['remark']))
                {
                    $remarks = $feed['remark'];
                }

                $update = Phone::find($phone_number);
                $update->network = $network;
                $update->country = $country;
                $update->country_prefix = $country_prefix;
                $update->status = $status;
                $update->remarks = $remarks;
                $update->save();
            }

        });


        // Get 13 records
        $phone = DB::connection('mysql')->select("SELECT * FROM phones WHERE status IS NULL LIMIT 13");
        foreach ($phone as $key => $value) 
        {    
            $request = new \cURL\Request($this->createCurlUrl($value->msisdn));
           // var_dump($this->createCurlUrl($value->msisdn)); exit;
            // Add request to queue
            $queue->attach($request);
        }

        // Process the queue
        while ($queue->socketPerform()) {
            $queue->socketSelect();
        }


        sleep(2);
        $y += 13; // Move to the next 13 records
    }

    Session::flash('alert-info', 'Data Updated Successfully!');
    return Redirect::to('upload');

}
```

Since the maximum is 20 request per seconds I'm just doing it 13 request per second just to be sure I won't clog their server. I am adding `sleep(2);` to pause a bit so that I can make sure that the queue is fully processed before moving on.